# HTML5 (?) doesn't understand empty element /> syntax from XML?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

This was the closest question to mine that I could find: [Closing empty elements and other xhtml standards within HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524183/closing-empty-elements-and-other-xhtml-standards-within-html5) and it leaves me disturbed, alarmed!

I have for decades used XML / XSLT to generate web pages. At some point I just used xsl:output type xml, not even html or xhtml. I thought: HTML is XML (at least somehow). But now, as I'm back actually typing HTML I find myself teleported to the early 1990s or something, where I have to write

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

instead of just

```
<script src="test.js"/>
```

and

```
<input>
<br>
<img>
```

don't need to be closed at all.

I sometimes do

```
<div/>
<p/>
```

and now I notice that the `/>` is entirely ignored and the p sucked into the contents of the div, leading to all kinds of confusion.

Isn't there some mode I can set on top, or by content-type or whatever it is where I can tell the browser to parse my document correctly as XML? I tried to begin the file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

but to no avail.

It feels like I'm the only one in the world who has completely missed the boat after decades of building web applications.

Comment: Hello Gunther. I find this area a bit baffling too. But what is the media type in the HTTP headers, does this affect things?

Comment: If you want to author XHTML according to XML syntax rules then make sure you serve your documents not as `text/html` but rather as `application/xhtml+xml` or as `application/xml`. So yes, it is the content type, set as as HTTP Content-Type header, that matters how the browser parses your document. If you load from the local file system then save as `.xml` or as `.xhtml` (for the latter I don't know how good it is supported on various platforms/OS).

Comment: Also note, once you go the XML route, for browser to recognize e.g. `p` or `div` or any other elements as XHTML elements, make sure you declare the XHTML namespace `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">..</html>` on the root element.

Comment: @MichaelKay, good that you would reply here, because I noticed when using Saxon-js that I need to be strictly XHTML and use the right namespace. In the other answer I see that the media type should be application/xhtml+xml, I wonder why not text/xml. I haven't tried it yet, probably different from browser to browser.

Comment: `application/xhtml+xml` works fine cross-browser. The last browser not to support it was Internet Explorer 8, which is now long gone.

Comment: @MartinHonnen but does text/xml not work? Only application/xhtml+xml or application/xml?

Comment: @GuntherSchadow, when I learned how to properly use the MIME type to ensure XML parsing for X(HT)ML documents (which was probably a decade and a half ago) someone seeming rather knowledgeable recommended not to go with text/xml due to various shortcomings/restrictions. I can't name them now, I don't know whether, like many things in the browser world, they have changed for good or worse, but I tend to use and recommend `application/xml` and `application/xhtml+xml` and it has worked out nice for me. If `text/xml` works for you, use it.